# Background image slideshow transition issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, transition

I need help in improving the script for my background image slideshow.

I managed to create a *fade in* effect with `.fadeIn(600)` JS function. But, I want the images to switch between each other, not between white background.

In other words, I need to smooth up the transition between images.

Note that each image has a caption, but I'm OK with it as it is. I don't need any transitions for text.

### JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/newsha/B4TXj/

```
    var timer;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // background image on load
    var numberImages = 4
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberImages; i++) {
        images.push(i);
    }
    var imgValue = 1
    $('.backgroundImage').addClass('bg' + imgValue + '');

    // Switch background image - forwards
    $('.imgSwitchRight').click(function () {
        $('.backgroundImage').each(function (e) {
            $(this).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').fadeOut(0);
        });
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.imgSwitchRight').click();
        }, 8000);
        if (imgValue < numberImages) {
            imgValue++
        } else {
            imgValue = 1
        }

        $('.backgroundImage').addClass('bg' + imgValue + '').fadeIn(600);

    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.imgSwitchRight').click();
    }, 8000);

    // Switch background - backwards
    $('.imgSwitchLeft').click(function () {
        $('.backgroundImage').each(function (e) {
            $(this).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').fadeOut(0);
        });
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.imgSwitchRight').click();
        }, 8000);

        if (imgValue > 1) {
            imgValue--
        } else {
            imgValue = numberImages
        }
        $('.backgroundImage').addClass('bg' + imgValue + '').fadeIn(600);

    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.imgSwitchRight').click();
    }, 8000);
});
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you hide all other images (via the `.bgx` classes) before you fade in the new one. Keep the current image visible while you fade in the new on, and only then hide it.

Comment: I recommend using [Backstretch as a slideshow](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). It's a great library for what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a secound div aas a swapping plane. the visible div is now fading out while the invisible one is fading in. after that the roles are switched and it goes on and on.. <strike>one problem still remains. if switching the images too fast the classes "stack" because the animation of the fading div is interrupted and the class will not be removed..</strike> Problem solved..

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // background image on load
    var numberImages = 5,
        easetime = 2000,
        changetimeout = 5000;

    var images = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberImages; i++) {
        images.push(i);
    }
    var imgValue = 1;
    var visibleBackground = $('.backgroundImage.a');
    var invisibleBackground = $('.backgroundImage.b');
    $('.backgroundImage').hide();
    visibleBackground.addClass('bg' + imgValue + '').show();

    var dir = 1;
    function changeBG(){
        oldValue = imgValue;
        imgValue = (imgValue+dir)%numberImages;
        $('.rotating-text'+imgValue).fadeIn(easetime);
        $('.rotating-text'+oldValue).fadeOut(easetime);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            changeBG();
        }, changetimeout);
        visibleBackground.fadeOut(easetime);
        setTimeout(function(){
            var tmpBackground = visibleBackground, tmpVal = oldValue;
            return function(){
                tmpBackground.removeClass('bg' + tmpVal)
            }
        }(), easetime);
        invisibleBackground.addClass('bg' + imgValue + '').fadeIn(easetime);

        var swap = visibleBackground;
        visibleBackground = invisibleBackground;
        invisibleBackground = swap;
    }

    // Switch background image - forwards
    $('.imgSwitchRight').click(function () {
        dir = 1;
        changeBG()
    });

    // Switch background - backwards
    $('.imgSwitchLeft').click(function () {
        dir = -1;
        changeBG()
    });
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        changeBG();
    }, changetimeout);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B4TXj/11/

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! But there is an issue with the back arrow - images stop showing up after a few clicks back. Is there anything we can do about it?

The class becomes bg-1, bg-2, instead of bg4, bg3

Comment: Another tiny issue - the rotating text doesn't show up on load.

Comment: Works! Thank you! Also, I managed to fix the back arrow issue by setting `$('.imgSwitchLeft').click(function () {dir = 3;` instead of -1 (dir = 3 is for 4 images, 4 for 5 etc.)

Comment: Better add this line `if(imgValue < 0) imgValue += numberImages;` after line 22. sry didn't noticed this bug.. http://jsfiddle.net/B4TXj/14/